# How to display information from database sqlite3 using GUI Tkinter in Python in a specific format?

Tags: python, sqlite, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to retrieve information from the database and display it in this certain way:

Name: Batman

Price: £ 18

But I am getting this error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable."

How can I fix that?

```
c.execute("SELECT name, price FROM products WHERE id=02")
    records = c.fetchone()
    # print(records)

    print_products = ''
    for record in records:
        print_products += 'Name:' + str(record[0]) + '\n' + 'Price: £' + str(record[1])

    query_label = Label(frame, fg='darkblue', bg='darkgray', text=print_products)
    query_label.pack()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only fetch one record from the result, `records` is a tuple of column values.  Then you use `for record in records:`, it means `record` is a column value that may be an integer. So using `record[0]` will raise the mentioned exception.

Actually you don't need the for loop at all:

```
c.execute("SELECT name, price FROM products WHERE id=02")
record = c.fetchone()

# check whether record exists
if record:
    print_products = 'Name:' + str(record[0]) + '\n' + 'Price: £' + str(record[1])

    query_label = Label(frame, fg='darkblue', bg='darkgray', text=print_products)
    query_label.pack()
```